# How to scroll the document(pdf,ppt,docx) horizontally in a uiwebview in ios?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a ppt file saved in the local cache. I want to load the ppt file with a horizontal scrolling in the uiwebview.Please give me a solution with examples.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to enable pagination on the UIWebView

```
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
```